# Typography in roadmarkings

Tags: design, info-visualisation, research, visual-design, typography

what kind of letter shapes function best for horizontal signing ?

I was wondering if anybody would know about the 
details in road mark typography?

In terms of function of the design itself, I have been trying to find any researches on type design experiments for road markings, but the only thing I've come up on is the research on elongated markings for horizontal perspectives.

So I was wondering : are there any specific studies on this subject?

Comment: I'm going to beg to differ on this one.  The question is very explicit: what typology is easiest to read at an angle ? (And this has application beyond road marking)

Comment: I second the motion. As a matter of fact, the original question was even more concise

Comment: hmm can you help me out here? can you give me an example of a question ?

Comment: To answer the posted question, I would go with any font that's probably twice as high as wide. But, more accurately, you can perform some geometry to figure out ratios based on typical driver eye level to ground (and how far out you want them to look).

Comment: Thanks @Cobalthex, i am more wondering about the letter design itself, in terms of X-height and porportion for example.

Comment: A random thought is that it might be worthwhile looking for research on airport runway fonts.

Comment: Are you asking about signage applied to the road surface itself?

Comment: @MMacD Yes Exactly!

Comment: This may be relevant: a quick Google revealed the UK's manual on road markings. More quick searches did not reveal any mention of font, although it does discuss the amount of elongation and in what conditions such elongation is required. Elongation is discussed in chapter 13.5.
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/223667/traffic-signs-manual-chapter-05.pdf

Comment: Furthermore, CBRD (an individual with a passion for UK roads) claims that the (unofficial) "Pavement" typeface is that which is used on UK roads:

http://www.cbrd.co.uk/fonts/

He notes that the typeface used on roads is supposed to be _Transport Medium_ (Pavement is), however _"In real life, it's rarely used, as almost all lettering on the road surface in the UK is hand-painted"_.

I recognize that CBRD isn't an ideal source, and that the UK is not all countries, and I would also posit that the point regarding hand-painting is true for most countries. It's just a data-point.

Comment: I believe the United States uses the "FHWA Pavement Markings and Symbol Series". The text part of the font appears to be depicted in detail here: http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/SHSe/pavement.pdf
I believe you can look at the complete font series (and buy it) here:
http://www.mutcd.org/en/products/fhwa/fhwa_symb_en.html

Comment: In regards to Australia, I found the following:
http://www.dpti.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0018/40257/DOCS_AND_FILES-2244015-v5-Pavement_Marking_Manual_May_2015.PDF
Which has a number of samples, but notes:
_"Letters and numerals other than those shown in Words (Part B 2.7.2) are available from Australian Standard 1742.2.
The length of letters and numerals shall be 2.5m where the speed limit is up to 80km/h and 5.0m at higher speed
limits unless otherwise specified"_. I was unable to acquire 'Standard 1742.2" for free.
Hope that's useful.

Comment: Particularly, have a look at the typeface DIN.

Answer (score 2):

I took a crack at this over several comments and I think I can provide some information on 50% of the question and that it's worth formalizing as an answer. **Before I begin, I don't have any studies, my apologies.**

> I was wondering if anybody would know about the details in road mark typography?

I looked up those pertaining to the United Kingdom, United States of America and Australia as these are all countries which speak English (and use English language characters as road signage), have stringent interest in road safety and are good candidates to have public documentation on it. This does not represent the entirety of knowledge or consensus on road markings, by any means!

**The United Kingdom:**

A quick Google revealed the [UK's manual on road markings](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/223667/traffic-signs-manual-chapter-05.pdf). More quick searches did not reveal any mention of font, although it does discuss the amount of elongation and in what conditions such elongation is required. Elongation is discussed in chapter 13.5.

> *Two sizes are prescribed for the legend,
>   1600 mm and 2800 mm. The smaller size is intended
>   to be used when the speed limit is 40mph or less,
>   and the larger when it is more than 40mph.*

Furthermore, [CBRD](http://cbrd.co.uk) (an individual with a passion for UK roads) claims on his website that the [(unofficially named) "Pavement" typeface](http://cbrd.co.uk/fonts) (scroll down) is that which is used on UK roads. He notes that the typeface used on roads is *supposed* to be [Transport Medium](https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Transport_Medium.font) (Pavement is Transport Medium elongated according to the rules), however he states:

> *In real life, it's rarely used, as almost all lettering on the road surface in the UK is hand-painted*

I recognize that CBRD isn't an ideal source, and I would also posit that the point regarding hand-painting is true for most countries.

**The United States:**
I believe the United States uses the [FHWA Pavement Markings and Symbol Series](http://mutcd.org/en/products/fhwa/fhwa_symb_en.html) as defined by the Federal Highway Administration's [Manual on Uniform Traffic Control Devices](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/). The text part of the font appears to be depicted in detail [here](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/SHSe/pavement.pdf).  I believe you can look at the complete font series (and buy it) [here](http://mutcd.org/en/products/fhwa/fhwa_symb_en.html); certainly the website (not related to the FHA) claim to offer solutions compliant with the MoUTCD.

**Australia:**

In regards to Australia, I found the [following](http://www.dpti.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0018/40257/DOCS_AND_FILES-2244015-v5-Pavement_Marking_Manual_May_2015.PDF) which has a number of samples, but notes:

> *Letters and numerals other than those shown in Words (Part B 2.7.2) are available from Australian Standard 1742.2. The length of letters and numerals shall be 2.5m where the speed limit is up to 80km/h and 5.0m at higher speed limits unless otherwise specified*

I was unable to acquire 'Standard 1742.2" for free.

I hope this is all of some use.